# Kafka JMX Metric Current Rate of Messages In

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx, prometheus

I have started Kafka broker instance locally with jmx_prometheus_javaagent as the java agent.

I am interested in current rate of messages coming in for a given topic and render same in a Grafana dashboard. Exploring the MBean in jconsole, I can see there a object named `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=ABCD` with attributes like MeanRate, OneMinuteRate,Count etc which seems to serve my purpose :-[image]

In order to try out my setup, I am sending very small sized messages to the local kafka brokers using a simple KafkaProducer that is able to send 1 million messages in less than 5s and then stops. For this experiment I was expecting to see a spike in MeanRate for those 5s and then back to 0 after that.

**PROBLEM**

Even when there no messages coming in (the producer has stopped ) I see a non zero high value for MeanRate long after the producer has stopped sending messages:-
[image: after stopping producer]

Same is reflected in Prometheus graph as:-

[image]

Prometheus Config :-

```
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+)><>MeanRate
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2_mean_rate
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
```

Prometheus Query - `floor(kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_mean_rate)`

What is the right way/prometheus-query/mbean to get an accurate rate of messages coming in ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `Count` and take a `rate()` of it on the Prometheus side. The [example config file](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml) that comes with the JMX exporter already selects the right metric for you.

MeanRate is the average rate per second since the binary started, accordingly it's not very useful. OneMinuteRate, FiveMinuteRate and FifteenMinuteRate are exponential moving averages, so would also decay over time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA has more information on various ways counters are handled by different instrumentation/monitoring systems.

Comment: sum without(instance)(rate(kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_total{job="kafka-vir",topic!="__consumer_offsets",topic!=""}[25s] ))

Yup. this worked fine for me. Thanks

Comment: Is that metric a count of events from the producer or does it also include replication events from other producers

Comment: @brian Where can I find the documentation for the metrics with _count _95thPercentile, _fiveminuterate things. I am getting confused on these metrics definitions.